# Python Scrapy ReactorNotRestartable()

Tags: python, scrapy, ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Scrapy on IBM cloud as a function. My `__main__.py` is as follows:

```
class AutoscoutListSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vehicles list"

    def __init__(self, params, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AutoscoutListSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        make = params.get("make", None)
        model = params.get("model", None)
        mileage = params.get("mileage", None)

        init_url = "https://www.autoscout24.be/nl/resultaten?sort=standard&desc=0&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&page=1&cy=B&mmvmd0={0}&mmvmk0={1}&kmto={2}&atype=C&".format(
            model, make, mileage)
        self.start_urls = [init_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get total result on list load
        init_total_results = int(response.css('.cl-filters-summary-counter::text').extract_first().replace('.', ''))
        if init_total_results > 400:
            yield {"message": "There are MORE then 400 results"}
        else:
            yield {"message": "There are LESS then 400 results"}


def main(params):
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    try:
        runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
        runner.crawl(AutoscoutListSpider, params)
        d = runner.join()
        d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run()
        return {"Success ": main_result}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"Error ": e, "params ": params}
```

I upload it to the as an IBM function, that is fine.

But the problem is when I run it, in `python console` or when I `invoke IBM function`, first time it's executed, but if I want to execute it second time I get an error:

```
{'Error ': ReactorNotRestartable(), 'params ': {'make': '9', 'model': '1624', 'mileage': '2500'}}
```

It is invoked like this:

**IBM**:

```
ibmcloud wsk action invoke --result ascrawler --param make 9 --param model 1624 --param mileage 2500
```

**Python console**:

```
main({"make":"9", "model":"1624", "mileage":"2500"})
```

With next code I've tried add a possibility to run it multiple times, but without success.

```
runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
runner.crawl(AutoscoutListSpider, params)
d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: This is more like lambda? If so, it may not mean fresh restart everytime. You should try the request after sometime and see if it works then?

Comment: How do you invoke it? How long does it run?

Comment: @data_henrik From `python console` I invoke it as follows: `main({"make":"9", "model":"1624", "mileage":"2500"})`. And as `IBM action` : `ibmcloud wsk action invoke --result ascrawler --param make 9 --param model 1624 --param mileage 2500` . But nothing wrong there otherwise it wouldn't run first time

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use the CrawlerRunner rather than CrawlerProcess?

According to the documentation, CrawlerRunner should be used instead of CrawlerProcess *"if your application is already using Twisted and you want to run Scrapy in the same reactor."* This is not the case for Python actions on IBM Cloud Functions.

Changing the `main` method to the following code, it works correctly.

```
def main(params):
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    try:
        process.crawl(AutoscoutListSpider, params)
        process.start()
        return {"Success ": params}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"Error ": e, "params ": params}
```

Comment: This gives a ReactorNotRestartable error. See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083449/reactornotrestartable-with-scrapy-when-using-google-cloud-functions