# ReactorNotRestartable with scrapy when using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, scrapy, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send multiple crawl requests with Google Cloud Functions. However, I seem to be getting the `ReactorNotRestartable` error. From other posts on StackOverflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495052/scrapy-reactor-not-restartable), I understand that this comes because it is not possible to restart the reactor, in particular when doing a loop.

The way to solve this is by putting the `start()` outside the for loop. However, with Cloud Functions this is not possible as each request should be technically independent.

Is the `CrawlerProcess` somehow cached with Cloud Functions? And if so, how can we remove this behaviour.

I tried for instance to put the import and initialization process inside a function, instead of outside, to prevent the caching of imports, but that did not work:

```py
# main.py

def run_single_crawl(data, context):
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    process = CrawlerProcess()

    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the asynchronous nature of `scrapy` is not going to work well with Cloud Functions, as we'd need a way to block on the crawl to prevent the function from returning early and the instance being killed before the process terminates.

Instead, we can use [`scrapydo`](https://pypi.org/project/scrapydo/) to run your existing spider in a blocking fashion:

`requirements.txt`:

```
scrapydo
```

`main.py`:

```py
import scrapy
import scrapydo

scrapydo.setup()


class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example.com"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://example.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield MyItem(url=response.url)


def run_single_crawl(data, context):
    results = scrapydo.run_spider(MySpider)
```

This also shows a simple example of how to yield one or more `scrapy.Item` from the spider and collect the results from the crawl, which would also be challenging to do if not using `scrapydo`.

Also: make sure that you have billing enabled for your project. By default Cloud Functions cannot make outbound requests, and the crawler will succeed, but return no results.

Comment: Hallelujah this seems to be working. I will accept your answer if all goes well with my test and time passed as this question has a bounty, so cannot accept it yet. But wow, I have no idea what this does but what a relief it would work.

Comment: I really like this solution as well, as I had the exact same issue in Azure Functions. It does work very well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply crawl the spider in a sequence.

## main.py

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
def run_single_crawl(data, context):
    process = CrawlerProcess()

    process.crawl(MySpider1)
    process.crawl(MySpider2)
    process.start()
```